# How to add a new Tab in an Itop 2.4?

Tags: cmdb

I have been trying to add a new tab as displayed in the image. I'm working on iTop 2.4
Can Anyone explain to me how to do this?[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have to create your own iTop extension and use the **iApplicationUIExtension::OnDisplayRelations($oObject, WebPage $oPage, $bEditMode = false)** API which provides you the current object so you can check its class and display the tab or not. It also gives you access to $oPage object so you can add your content to the tab.

If you are not familiar with iTop extension development, check [this page](https://www.itophub.io/wiki/page?id=2_7_0%3Acustomization%3Aadd-attribute-sample) which explains everything (note that it's for iTop 2.7 but the API is the same for iTop 2.4).

Here is an example from the "Approval process automation" extension:

```
class ApprovalBasePlugin implements iApplicationUIExtension, iApplicationObjectExtension
{
    ...

    public function OnDisplayRelations($oObject, WebPage $oPage, $bEditMode = false)
    {
        if (!$oObject instanceof Ticket)
        {
            // skip !
            return;
        }

        ...

        // Set the new tab name
        $oPage->SetCurrentTab(Dict::S('Approval:Tab:Title'));

        ...
 
        // Add content through the \WebPage APIs
        $oPage->add('<div id="'.$sId.'_status" class="approval-exec-status">');
        $oPage->add($oScheme->GetDisplayStatus($oPage, $bEditMode));
        $oPage->add('</div>');

        ...
    }

    ...
}
```